# how to make calculator using javascript using on text box for input value and perform add and subtract using button

Tags: javascript, html

As below you can see I want perform calculation of adding and subtracting but the program not giving output of calculation. there is input box for operator 1 and operator 2. I create two function add and sub. And using `document.getElementById` I pass the value of a and b and want to calculate but the function is does not giving output.

```html
         <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>Document</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            
                Operator1:<input type="text" id="a">
                <br><br>
                Operator2:<input type="text" id="b">
              <br><br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="button" value="Add" id="add" onclick="addd()">
                <input type="button" value="sub" id="sub" onclick="subb()">
                <br><br>
            
               Result: <input type="text" id="res">
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               
                <script>
                    function addd(){
                var ra= document.getElementById('a').value;
                var rb=document.getElementById('b').value;
                var rab=ra+rb;
               Document.getElementById('res').value==rab;
                    }
            
                    function subb(){
                var ra= document.getElementById('a').value;
                var rb=document.getElementById('b').value;
                var rab=ra-rb;
               document.getElementById('res').value==rab;
                    }
                </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: It's `document.getElementById()`, not `Document.getElementById()`. Open your browser's developer tools (F12) and look at the Console, you will see an error message there.

Comment: Also `&nbsp;` is not meant to be used for margins and padding of elements like you are doing.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `=` and `==`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure you're using the assignment operator, instead of the comparison operator.

Try `document.getElementById('res').value = rab;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide an example that you'll hopefully learn from, but I really recommend you go and learn the basics before you continue programming.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>input[type=number], button { display:inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="number" id="input-a">
        <input type="number" id="input-b"><br>
        <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
        <button type="button" id="subtract">Subtract</button><br>
        <input type="number" id="result" disabled>
        <script>
            const resultElement = document.querySelector("#result");
            const inputAElement = document.querySelector("#input-a");
            const inputBElement = document.querySelector("#input-b");
        
            document.querySelector("#add").addEventListener("click", event => {
                resultElement.value = +inputAElement.value + +inputBElement.value;
            });
            
            document.querySelector("#subtract").addEventListener("click", event => {
                resultElement.value = +inputAElement.value - +inputBElement.value;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The only thing that's not self-explanatory here is the actual calculation. Notice how I put a + at the start of each value `+inputAElement.value`? That's to cast the value to a number for the calculation. Otherwise in certain situations, the value could be treated as a text value and just mashed together (e.g. `5 + 1 = 51`).

Use CSS styles to change the look, as shown in the `style` tag. Abusing `&nbsp;` won't make you any friends.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>input[type=number], button { display:inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="number" id="input-a">
        <input type="number" id="input-b"><br>
        <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
        <button type="button" id="subtract">Subtract</button><br>
        <input type="number" id="result" disabled>
        <script>
            const resultElement = document.querySelector("#result");
            const inputAElement = document.querySelector("#input-a");
            const inputBElement = document.querySelector("#input-b");
        
            document.querySelector("#add").addEventListener("click", event => {
                resultElement.value = +inputAElement.value + +inputBElement.value;
            });
            
            document.querySelector("#subtract").addEventListener("click", event => {
                resultElement.value = +inputAElement.value - +inputBElement.value;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```